# That story about not-so-careful Hans is called 'Careful Hans'

Tags: phrase-meaning, names

There's the very popular children's story called *Careful Hans*.

> *Careful Hans* is a story about a not-so-careful and foolish boy, Hans.

**Why is this so?** I understand the name of a story doesn't necessarily have to make sense, but it can't be contradictory to the story itself.

**Is this supposed to be ironic?** (But children don't really understand irony, do they?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  
this question is not about the English language per se. It belongs on another site, perhaps one about children's stories or folk tales, or child psychology

Comment: It's meant to be ironic, and many children understand irony perfectly well.  :)

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You're misunderstanding me. This is not at all related to child psychology or the likes. That last line was just a question tag meant to imply that I don't think children understand irony and so the title being ironic seems unlikely to me. That was no question; only the sentences in bold are questions. I bracketed the last line to make my purpose clear.

Comment: You might add what irony you are thinking of. And, does Hans become careful by the end of the story? I agree with @Tᴚoɯɐuo that this is literary evaluation, and not about learning the English language. You might want to check if on-topic at Literature SE.

Comment: @Soha Farhin Pine: And  I think you're misunderstanding me. Do you not understand what is meant by "not about the English language *per se*" ? Fluent native speakers could have different opinions about whether there is irony there, or not.  You're asking for literary opinions. We don't do that here.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Well, is asking whether or not a particular sentence or a sentence fragment is ironic, off-topic? Why then is it the case with my question? I don't really understand your point. All people can have different opinions on a topic. `Is "I hate you, my love." ironic?` You can say that the speaker's just joking. Someone else could say it's pure sarcasm. Another could say, yes, it's ironic. But does that mean the question isn't valid? (Silly example, I know.)

Comment: @Soha Farhin Pine: It would be on topic to ask what is meant when someone from Boston, say, tells you that your English is "wicked good". But to ask whether an author is being ironic in the choice of title for a literary work is off-topic.  If falls under the rubric of "Criticism, discussion, and analysis of English literature", which is off-topic here, per the site's guidelines.  If the question involves a literary work (broadly construed) we allow only questions about the *literal*  meaning or grammatical role of the words, or how to parse the sentence.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I understand, but I *am* asking about the title's literal meaning and how to parse that. Guess, I don't even know my own intentions.

Comment: The literal meaning is adjective + noun.   Reckless Joe: a guy named Joe who was reckless.   A guy named Hans who was careful.

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine If you were to read the story and truly understand it, the answer to your question would be obvious to you. This forces me to ask: have you read and understood the story? Do you understand why parents read stories to their children, and what children's stories are meant to teach, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether the story is derived from the Brothers Grimm fairy tale entitled [Clever Hans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clever_Hans_(fairy_tale)), but the title is probably a reference to it.

In the Grimm tale, Clever Hans keeps doing foolish things. As the wiki article says, "The title is claimed by most people to be ironic.", and the same is probably true of James Hassett's book **Careful Hans**.

Comment: But children don't really understand irony, do they?

Comment: Oh yes they do!!! https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/09/100914143430.htm

Comment: Wow. Great article. Hadn't known that. Well, children are often underestimated. You can incorporate this info into your answer.

Comment: LOL! My daughter _invented_ irony when she was six!